# Mod_Wsgi missing symbol

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, alpine-linux

I'm building an Alpine Docker image for deploying Python web applications.

The image I use contains Alpine-3.7, Python-3.6.5 and Apache2.4 with mod_wsgi4.6.4 (downloaded from pip3). Whenever I try to start my apache2 server, I get the following errors:

```
[Thu Jul 05 09:56:16.257991 2018] [so:debug] [pid 97] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module authn_file_module from /var/www/modules/mod_authn_file.so
[Thu Jul 05 09:56:16.258274 2018] [so:debug] [pid 97] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module authn_core_module from /var/www/modules/mod_authn_core.so
[Thu Jul 05 09:56:16.258385 2018] [so:debug] [pid 97] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module authz_host_module from /var/www/modules/mod_authz_host.so
[Thu Jul 05 09:56:16.258486 2018] [so:debug] [pid 97] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module authz_groupfile_module from /var/www/modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
[Thu Jul 05 09:56:16.258701 2018] [so:debug] [pid 97] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module authz_user_module from /var/www/modules/mod_authz_user.so
[Thu Jul 05 09:56:16.258805 2018] [so:debug] [pid 97] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module authz_core_module from /var/www/modules/mod_authz_core.so
[Thu Jul 05 09:56:16.258888 2018] [so:debug] [pid 97] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module access_compat_module from /var/www/modules/mod_access_compat.so
[Thu Jul 05 09:56:16.258981 2018] [so:debug] [pid 97] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module auth_basic_module from /var/www/modules/mod_auth_basic.so
[Thu Jul 05 09:56:16.259478 2018] [so:debug] [pid 97] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module reqtimeout_module from /var/www/modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
[Thu Jul 05 09:56:16.259660 2018] [so:debug] [pid 97] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module filter_module from /var/www/modules/mod_filter.so
[Thu Jul 05 09:56:16.259768 2018] [so:debug] [pid 97] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module mime_module from /var/www/modules/mod_mime.so
[Thu Jul 05 09:56:16.260283 2018] [so:debug] [pid 97] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module log_config_module from /var/www/modules/mod_log_config.so
[Thu Jul 05 09:56:16.260450 2018] [so:debug] [pid 97] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module env_module from /var/www/modules/mod_env.so
[Thu Jul 05 09:56:16.260586 2018] [so:debug] [pid 97] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module headers_module from /var/www/modules/mod_headers.so
[Thu Jul 05 09:56:16.260881 2018] [so:debug] [pid 97] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module setenvif_module from /var/www/modules/mod_setenvif.so
[Thu Jul 05 09:56:16.260993 2018] [so:debug] [pid 97] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module version_module from /var/www/modules/mod_version.so
[Thu Jul 05 09:56:16.261445 2018] [so:debug] [pid 97] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module mpm_worker_module from /var/www/modules/mod_mpm_worker.so
[Thu Jul 05 09:56:16.261734 2018] [so:debug] [pid 97:tid 140172276706184] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module unixd_module from /var/www/modules/mod_unixd.so
[Thu Jul 05 09:56:16.261839 2018] [so:debug] [pid 97:tid 140172276706184] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module status_module from /var/www/modules/mod_status.so
[Thu Jul 05 09:56:16.261951 2018] [so:debug] [pid 97:tid 140172276706184] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module autoindex_module from /var/www/modules/mod_autoindex.so
[Thu Jul 05 09:56:16.262576 2018] [so:debug] [pid 97:tid 140172276706184] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module dir_module from /var/www/modules/mod_dir.so
[Thu Jul 05 09:56:16.262747 2018] [so:debug] [pid 97:tid 140172276706184] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module alias_module from /var/www/modules/mod_alias.so
[Thu Jul 05 09:56:16.262869 2018] [so:debug] [pid 97:tid 140172276706184] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module negotiation_module from /var/www/modules/mod_negotiation.so
httpd: Syntax error on line 484 of /etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: Error relocating /var/www/modules/mod_wsgi.so: __sprintf_chk: symbol not found
```

(I just appended `LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so` at the end of my httpd.conf).

PS: For information (I don't know if it is relevant or not), I installed those packages with apk: `musl musl-dev apache2 apache2-utils apache2-dev gcc python3-dev`... I guess my error has something to do with musl/musl-dev but I think that it's quite weird...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't know which of those solutions solved the problem, but I don't have the error anymore.

I added the packages `libc-dev make`, and rebuilt the last version of mod_wsgi from source code. I don't have the error anymore.